# Add floats yields Double

Tags: groovy

This groovy:

```
float a = 1;
float b = 2;
def r = a + b;
```

Creates this Java code when reversed from .class with IntelliJ:

```
float a = (float)1;
float b = (float)2;
Object r = null;
double var7 = (double)a + (double)b;
r = Double.valueOf(var7);
```

So `r` contains a `Double`.

If I do this:

```
float a = 1;
float b = 2;
float r = a + b;
```

It generates code that performs the addition with doubles and converts back to float:

```
float a = (float)1;
float b = (float)2;
float r = 0.0F;
double var7 = (double)a + (double)b;
r = (float)var7;
```

So should one abandon `float`s with groovy as it seems to not want to use them anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groovy decided to take 5 standard result types of numeric operations. fall back to certain standard numeric types for operations. Those are int, long, BigInteger, double and BigDecimal. Thus adding/multiplying two floats returns a double. Division and pow are special.

From http://www.groovy-lang.org/syntax.html

> Division and power binary operations aside,
>
> - binary operations between byte, char, short and int result in int
> - binary operations involving long with byte, char, short and int result
>     in long
> - binary operations involving BigInteger and any other integral type
>     result in BigInteger
> - binary operations between float, double and BigDecimal result in
>     double
> - binary operations between two BigDecimal result in BigDecimal

As for if you should abandon `float`... normally it is good enough to convert the double to float, especially since groovy is doing that automatically for you.

Comment: Thanks, though you list 5 types. Do you have a link I might see this info on? It seems strange that they don't force you to 64 bit ints, but they force you to 64 bit floats.

Comment: Never mind I found it and added to back up your answer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

.net (C#) does something similar with 16-bit integers: Addition of Bytes or Int16s yield Int32. **Possibly to prevent overflows.**

Operations with "smaller" data types may result in the "bigger" data types. And with bigger, I mean more bits.

As illustrated in this example (more digits also means more bits)

15 (2 digits) x 15 (2 digits) = 225 (3 digits)

1.5 (2 digits) x 1.5 (2 digits) = 2.25 (3 digits)

However, adding two 32 bit integers returns jus a 32 bit integer. And adding two doubles just returns a double. This is because the (virtual) machine is optimized for working with these sizes, which is because physical processors used to be optimized for working with these sizes. Some of them still are. 32 bit operations are often still faster than 64 bit operations, even on 64 bit processors. However, 16 bit operations are not or barely.

Your compiler attempts to protect you against overflows, and allows you to check for them explicitly. So unless you have a good reason not to, I'd default to using these types, and optionally trunc to a compacter type when storing the data.

Good reasons **not** to include scenarios where you process large amounts (1000s) of numbers, e.g. for graphic processing.

Comment: Got any links to support "Java ... prefer[s] doubles and integers" I found this to the contrary: ["...Otherwise, the operation is carried out using 32-bit floating-point arithmetic, and the result of the numerical operator is a value of type float"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.4).

Comment: @weston: I interpreted from the question that the JVM (and classes) worked that way. They apperently do not. Thanks, I corrected my answer.